# discord.js and node.js module not exporting correctly? returned statement not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

So Im trying to get a couple messages returned from a specific channel to get info about 'clans' that were registered before. However I can fetch the channel and all and then I can filter and loop through the returned messages but I cannot return the messages that I fetched no matter what. No Error no nothing but if you call .getClans from another file it always returns undefined.

```js
module.exports.getClans = (guild, channelid) => {
    var channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelid);

    channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 10 }).then(messages => {
            messages = messages.filter(msg => msg.content && msg.content.startsWith("clan{") && msg.author.bot==true);

            return messages
        }
    )
}
```

I have even done things such as

```
module.exports.getClans = (guild, channelid) => {
    var channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelid);

    channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 10 }).then(messages => {
            messages = messages.filter(msg => msg.content && msg.content.startsWith("clan{") && msg.author.bot==true);

            var returned = []

            messages.forEach((el) =>{
                returned.push(el)
            })

            return returned;
        }
    )
}
```

which I checked in the module function itself returned was defined but calling the function again returned nothing other than undefined. Please help I have no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually returning anything from the function, you are only returning from the `.then(messages, ...)`. You will need to retrieve what is being fetched and then return.

```
module.exports.getClans = (guild, channelid) => {
     var channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelid);
     
     //This return is returning from .getClans()
     return channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 10 }).then(messages => {
            messages = messages.filter(msg => msg.content && msg.content.startsWith("clan{") && msg.author.bot==true);
            
            //This return is returning from inside the .then()
            return messages
        }
    )
}
```